# Permission denied Setuptools

Tags: python, django, curl, setuptools

I'm trying install setuptools in my Mac, but when I run command `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python` show a message telling:

```
   Processing setuptools-17.1.1-py3.4.egg
   Removing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-17.1.1-py3.4.egg
   Copying setuptools-17.1.1-py3.4.egg to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
   Adding setuptools 17.1.1 to easy-install.pth file error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/easy-install.pth'
   Something went wrong during the installation.
   See the error message above.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `sudo` for the python command to write to `/Library/Frameworks...`:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo  python
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to run as root, using `sudo`. This should be googlable. :)

see also:

- [Errno 13](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Errno+13)
- [What is root?](http://www.linfo.org/root.html)
- [The Command Line Crash Course](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/)